# Rolling Std returns 0 for pandas DataFrame after multiplying with 1e-1

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, precision

Does anyone know why rolling std returns 0 after it reaches a factor of 1e-8 for a float64 pandas data frame column?

Here is a code example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 250
pd.set_option('display.precision', 200)
df = pd.DataFrame()

df["C"] = [np.random.normal() for i in range(10000)]

print("N(0, 1)")
print(df["C"].mean())
print(df["C"].std())

# 1e0
df["std"] = df["C"].rolling(N).std()
print("Std is not 0.")
print(df["std"])

# 1e-6
df["C"] = df["C"] * 1e-6
df["std"] = df["C"].rolling(N).std()
print("Std is still not 0.")
print(df["std"])

# 1e-7
df["C"] = df["C"] * 1e-1
df["std"] = df["C"].rolling(N).std()
print("Std is sometimes (?) 0 now.")
print(df["std"])

# 1e-8
df["C"] = df["C"] * 1e-1
df["std"] = df["C"].rolling(N).std()
print("Std is always 0 now.")
print(df["std"])
```

1e-8 should not be the problem, as we are working with float64 here and std without rolling can handle even smaller numbers. The same issue occurs when multiplying with 1e-8 directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one alternative via `np.std`:

```
import numpy as np
df = df["C"].rolling(N).apply(np.std)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still wondering why this issue occurs.